# I can't split my function into sub functions because of a static variable

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free

I'm still writing my own implementation of `get_next_line`, a function that takes a file descriptor and outputs the line of the file, then the next line and so on, since my last post, but now everything is working in my code !

The problem is, in the norms I have to follow, my code have to be less than 25 lines, and my function is actually 30. I successfully split into one sub function but I need to split it one more time but this time, I get invalid frees or invalid reads and completely wrong results.

*(I have a get_next_line_utils.c that contains homemade libc functions and it has a strjoin that frees the stash in parameter because it creates a new one)*

Here is my working code :

```
static int  check_line(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    if (!str)
        return (-1);
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] == '\n')
            return (1);
        i++;
    }
    return (-1);
}

/*
    ft_strcut is used in one case in GNL.
    When the stash contains a \n, we are cutting the string
    from the \n to the end of the string, so our new stash does not
    longer contain the \n ans the past line.
*/

static char *ft_strcut(char *str)
{
    char    *cutted_str;
    int     i;
    int     j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\n')
        i++;
    cutted_str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (ft_strlen(str) - i + 1));
    if (!cutted_str)
        return (NULL);
    i++;
    while (str[i])
        cutted_str[j++] = str[i++];
    cutted_str[j] = '\0';
    free(str);
    return (cutted_str);
}

/*
    I used this function to make GNL less than 25 lines.
    This block of code was between the variable declaration and the while loop.
    This function is checking the validity of fd, BUFFER_SIZE and the stash.
    And it's initializing our stash for the rest of GNL if the verification passed.
*/

static char *stash_checking(int fd, char *stash, char *buff, int readed)
{
    if (fd < 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0)
        return (NULL);
    buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
    if (!buff)
        return (NULL);
    readed = read(fd, buff, BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (readed <= 0 && !stash)
    {
        free(buff);
        return (NULL);
    }
    buff[readed] = '\0';
    if (!stash)
            stash = ft_substr(buff, 0, ft_strlen(buff)); //It's like strdup
    else
        stash = ft_strjoin(stash, buff);
    free(buff);
    if (stash[0] == '\0')
    {
        free(stash);
        stash = NULL;
        return (NULL);
    }
    return (stash);
}

char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char *stash; //Static variable to keep the stash between calls.
    char        *buff;  //Buffer to read the file.
    char        *line;  //Line to return.
    int         readed; //Readed bytes.

    readed = 0;
    buff = NULL;
    stash = stash_checking(fd, stash, buff, readed);
    while (stash)
    {
        buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
        readed = read(fd, buff, BUFFER_SIZE);
        buff[readed] = '\0';
        stash = ft_strjoin(stash, buff);
        free(buff);
        if (readed < BUFFER_SIZE && check_line(stash) == -1)
            {
                line = ft_substr(stash, 0, ft_strlen(stash)); //It's like strdup
                free(stash);
                stash = NULL;
                return (line);
            }
        else if (check_line(stash) != -1)
        {
            line = ft_substr(stash, 0, ft_strchr(stash, '\n') - stash + 1);
            stash = ft_strcut(stash);
            return (line);
        }
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

As you can see, I successfully split a chunk of code into a function named `stash_checking` to make my code shorter but it is not enough.

I tried to put the lines from `if (readed < BUFFER_SIZE && check_line(stash) == -1)` to the end of `else if`
in a sub function that I named `handling_cases` and I'm getting a `double free()` error.

```
static char *handling_cases(int readed, char *stash, char *line)
{
    if (readed < BUFFER_SIZE && check_line(stash) == -1)
    {
        line = ft_substr(stash, 0, ft_strlen(stash));
        free(stash);
        stash = NULL;
        return (line);
    }
    else if (check_line(stash) != -1)
    {
        line = ft_substr(stash, 0, ft_strchr(stash, '\n') - stash + 1);
        stash = ft_strcut(stash);
        return (line);
    }
    return (NULL);
}

char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char *stash; //Static variable to keep the stash between calls.
    char        *buff;  //Buffer to read the file.
    char        *line;  //Line to return.
    int         readed; //Readed bytes.

    readed = 0;
    buff = NULL;
    stash = stash_checking(fd, stash, buff, readed);
    while (stash)
    {
        buff = malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
        readed = read(fd, buff, BUFFER_SIZE);
        buff[readed] = '\0';
        stash = ft_strjoin(stash, buff);
        free(buff);
        line = handling_cases(readed, stash, line);
        if (line)
            return (line);
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

I have tested a lot of similar things, putting all the `while` loop in a sub function that returns the `line` and many different things but I don't understand why, I'm getting some double frees, invalid write or not expected output.

I would like to understand why putting the exact chunk of code in a separate function is doing errors.

I debugged my code, and it seem's my stash is not correctly freed, or always have no values in it when I call GNL at the end of the file.

I'm sorry if this is a little confusing, my english is not perfect yet..

Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: If all you care about is the line count, just put things like `readed = 0; buff = NULL;` on the same line.  Also collapse the definitions of `buff` and `line` to `char *buff, *line;`.

Comment: @SteveSummit I can't do that following the norms of my school, I don't think I can make my code shorter but splitting into sub functions.

Comment: When you pass the `stash` and `line` variables, you're working on copies of the pointer in the `handling_cases` function, so the value of the `stash` and `line` variables are not affected in `get_next_line`

Comment: Coding style is all about tradeoffs.  Yes, in general, shorter functions are good.  But if you split one cohesive chunk of code into two separate functions, but they need to have some shared data, that used to be a static variable, now you may need a global variable, and that's bad.  Sometimes you may choose to break one guideline in order to follow another one.

Comment: However, in this case, if you do need a global variable to coordinate state between the two functions, you can use a file-scope — that is, `static` — global, and that's often a fine compromise.

Comment: @SteveSummit Sorry, I can't use global variables either

Comment: @nokosse No need to apologize.  Your school's guidelines don't apply to me. :-)  I'm just making suggestions; it's up to you whether you choose to use them or not. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with passing `stash` is kind-of correct, but you missed one thing: You need to pass a **pointer** to the variable to a called function. This resembles "pass by reference" in C, which only has "pass by value".

It does not matter, whether such a variable is `static` or not. The called function does not need to know, and you cannot make it know.

I have simplified your example and used generic names:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void called(int **pointer_to_pointer) {
  int value = 42;

  if (*pointer_to_pointer != NULL) {
    value = **pointer_to_pointer;
    //free(*pointer_to_pointer);
  }

  *pointer_to_pointer = malloc(sizeof **pointer_to_pointer);
  **pointer_to_pointer = value + 1;
  printf("%s(): %p -> %p -> %d\n", __FUNCTION__, (void*)pointer_to_pointer, (void*)*pointer_to_pointer, **pointer_to_pointer);
}

static void caller(void) {
  static int *pointer = NULL;
  int value = 23;

  if (pointer != NULL) {
    value = *pointer;
    //free(pointer);
  }

  pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer);
  *pointer = value + 1;
  printf("%s(): @ %p: %p -> %d\n", __FUNCTION__, (void*)&pointer, (void*)pointer, *pointer);

  called(&pointer);
  printf("%s(): @ %p: %p -> %d\n", __FUNCTION__, (void*)&pointer, (void*)pointer, *pointer);

  called(&pointer);
  printf("%s(): @ %p: %p -> %d\n", __FUNCTION__, (void*)&pointer, (void*)pointer, *pointer);
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%s()\n", __FUNCTION__);
  caller();
  printf("%s()\n", __FUNCTION__);
  caller();
  printf("%s()\n", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

Some notes:

- Because in my environment `malloc()` returned exactly the same memory that was just `free()`ed, I needed to comment those calls to show that new memory was allocated.
- The size in the calls of `malloc()` uses the `sizeof` operator with the expression that "is" the wanted object. You can keep using the parenthesized version of this operator with a data type, like `sizeof (int)` for this demonstration program.
- Here is no error check after calling `malloc()`. Don't do this in production code.
- `__FUNCTION__` is a nice predefined preprocessor macro of GCC and Clang, which expands to the name of the current function as a C string.
- `printf()` expects `void*` for its format specifier `"%p"`, so every pointer value is correctly cast.